# pyqt Window similar to Win32 style

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm trying to port a Win32 app to Python using pyqt for the GUI, but I can't seem to get a simple window with a text label and edit field such as the following simple Win32 style (basically WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE):

[image: Example]

I played with setFrameStyle (ie using different styles and sunken - and then for a good measure all other sensible combinations) of the two widgets and used setContentsMargins() to zero to get it to fill all the space, but the qt window still looks quite different with regard to the border.

Comment: You may have looked at this already but have you looked at the Python `win32gui` module - this is part of the [Python win32 extensions](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html) ?  This may allow you to port your app more closely to what you expect.  PyQt are custom controls, so I would expect you can get close to what you want, but you may never match exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I looked at some different GUI frameworks, but I'm using Python3 and that limits the range quite a bit and pyqt seems to be the best bet - I played a bit longer and got it somewhat similar if you look not too much into it, so it'll have to do for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get pretty close with the following (using QtGui.QFrame.WinPanel):

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        label = QtGui.QLabel("Test")
        label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.WinPanel | QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)

        edit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        edit.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.WinPanel | QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        edit.setText("Some text")
        edit.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.MoveOperation.End)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1)
        vbox.setSpacing(1)
        vbox.addWidget(label)
        vbox.addWidget(edit)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window Title')
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[QFrame](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QFrame.html) docs has an excellent overview of different frame styles.

To get closer than setFrameStyle allows, you need to paint you own widgets/panels, or use something other than QT.

[wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org)

[pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using the right style. Have a look at [the documentation for QStyle](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/qstyle.html#id-bc093402-0183-4b15-b942-bb350df6fb51).